# How to instantiate HttpClient in windows form correctly

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

As per MSDN
HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors. Below is an example using HttpClient correctly.

```
public class GoodController : ApiController    
{    
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;    
    
    static GoodController()    
    {    
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();    
    }    
}
```

But in windows form (obviously controller doen't make sense here) , how to manage HttpClient in desktop application correctly, each instance of HttpClient opens a port on the server , so obviously multiple instances would not be good.

Comment: Create a singleton class that exports a single `HttpClient` that every object uses. `HttpClient` is thread safe as long as you use `SendAsync` in all your calls (i.e. don't modify any `Default...` headers)